# Problema en php + Mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Buenas, les cuento un poco de que va la cosa. Estoy realizando una página en php junto con Mysqli para las consultas e inserciones en base de datos. Estamos trabajando en localhost. Mi problema es el siguiente. 
-Una vez que registro a un usuario, no me toma los campos del formulario, y solo registra el campo de la PK, lo cual me parece raro, ya que están realizados de la misma manera. He probado distintas formas y no encuentro solución alguna :/.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <title>Registro de Usuario</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
</head>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="container">
   <h1>Registrate en Guppy!</h1>
  </div>
 </header>
 <section id="fondo">
 <div class="container">
  <section class="main row">
   <article class="col-md-6">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    Unete a la nueva red social que revolucionara el mundo! <br>
    Es totalmente gratis!
   </article>
   <aside class="col-xs-9 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <h1>REGISTRO</h1> <br>
    <form action="validarUsu.php" method="post">
     <table class="table">
      <tr>
       <td>Correo: </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="txtCorreo"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Nombre: </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="txtNombre"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Apellido: </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="txtApellido"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Clave: </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="txtClave"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td><button class="btn btn-primary">REGISTRARME</button></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </form>
   </aside>
  </section>
 </div>
 <br>
 </section>
 <footer>
  <div class="container">
   <h3><a href="index.html">Guppy</a></h3>
  </div>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```js
<script>
 function exito(){
  alert("Usuario Registrado Exitosamente");
  window.location = "index.html";
 }

 function camposVacios(){
  alert("Campos Vacíos!");
  window.location = "registrar.html";
 }
</script>

<?php  
 
 $correo   = trim($_POST["txtCorreo"]);
 $nombre   = trim($_POST["txtNombre"]);
 $apellido = trim($_POST["txtApellido"]);
 $clave    = trim($_POST["txtClave"]);

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "guppy");
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if ($correo == "" || $nombre = "" || $apellido = "" || $clave = "") {
 echo"<script>camposVacios()</script>";
}

else{

 $query = "INSERT INTO usuario (correo, nombre, apellido, clave) VALUES ('".$correo."', '".$nombre."','".$apellido."','".$clave."')";

 if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
     echo "<script>exito()</script>";
     
 } else {
     echo "Ocurrio un error inesperado: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
 }
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: puedes poner el código en la pregunta, stackoverflow tiene herramientas muy útiles para que se vea así, ya que es más fácil verlo todo junto que imagen por imagen, también pon tu estrucura de tu tabla

Comment: [Una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/). Por favor, dale a [edit] y añade aquí el texto.

Answer (score 0):

En tu sentencia INSERT INTO sólo indicas las variables php que vas a meter a la base de datos, pero no indicas a que parte de la base de datos lo vas a meter.

E.g.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Contacto (correo, nombre, apellido, clave) VALUES ('$correo', '$nombre', '$apellido', '$clave')";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo pase por alto!

Comment: No era eso el problema, me registra solo el correo y los demas campos los pasa por alto

Comment: Era el if el problema jajaja, estaba declarandolo asi $variable = ""; no así $variable == ""